# Why does my script stop rendering through my page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a script for my page that is supposed to make random letters bold in a sentence or paragraph bold.

```
let all = document.querySelectorAll("p, ol, ul, a, li, span, h2, h3, h4, h5");
all.forEach((a) => a.childNodes.forEach((b) => makeRandomBold(b)));

function makeRandomBold(node) {
  if (node.nodeType !== 3) {
    return;
  }
  let text = node.textContent;
  node.textContent = "";
  text.split("").forEach((s) => {
    if (s !== " " && Math.random() > 0.49) {
      let strong = document.createElement("strong");
      strong.textContent = s;
      node.parentNode.insertBefore(strong, node);
    } else {
      node.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(s), node);
    }
  });
}
```

I have added an image to provide a clear description of what I am talking about.

[image: erring image]

Comment: @user3783243 I apologise for deleting the question. I wanted to clarify it. I did not notice that I described my issue in the screenshot.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML that generates your screenshot when this javascript executes?

Comment: I took a screenshot. I struggled to edit the question. Here it is https://imgur.com/a/WEPaE74.

Comment: You don't search for `code` tag so why should it be replaced?

Comment: In my browser, `a.childNodes.forEach` doesn't seem to work correctly and produces the same output you get, however `[...a.childNodes].forEach` works.  Give that a try.